# How to program an unfair or biased coin flip in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, probability, coin-flipping

I need to make a coin flip that obeys a certain probability of outcome. For example, a coin flip with a 67% chance of coming out Heads, 83% chance of coming out Tails, etc.

I managed to get the result I'm after by populating an array with 100 `true` and `false` in the equivalent distribution, then picking one item at random. What is a more elegant way to go about it?

Comment: When asking, we expect one of two things: A minimal example of your code demonstrating the problem, or a list of the places you searched and an explanation why those didn't help you solve the problem. Read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Your question makes it look like you want us to write code solving the problem, which is not what Stack Overflow is for. Instead we're here to help you solve the problem by correcting your mistakes. Please show us your code.

Comment: I was looking for a different approach rather than a solution to the problem, as I already had code that effectively solved the problem, as described, but I was not happy with. What would be a more appropriate place to ask for something like that?

Comment: [codereview.se] is useful when you have working code and want to know if it could be written better. Your question as asked would be inappropriate there, just as it is questionable on SO because it's not clear how you've written your code. Discussing code is not as useful or efficient as presenting the minimal code necessary to demonstrate it.

Comment: I disagree, presenting the code I had written would be worse than useless, first because I was specifically asking for another approach, and second because it would likely mislead some people into thinking they should answer based on it, which was, again, completely our of the scope of the question. So I would get answers "optimizing" the useless code, which would not do anyone a service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Random#rand(max)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Random.html) (and [`Kernel#rand(max)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html)):

> When max is an Integer [greater than or equal to 1], rand returns a random integer greater than or equal to zero and less than max..

So:

```
p = rand(100)
return p < 83  # ie. true for heads
```

In theory such can be "exact" like an array distribution method.

Answer (score 7):

```
rand < 0.67
rand < 0.83
```

will give `true` with probability of 67% and 83%, respectively - because a uniformly selected random number `x` that is `0 <= x < 1` (such as returned by [`Kernel#rand`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-rand)) will be 67% likely to land in the segment `0 <= x < 0.67`.

Comment: I'm going to have to accept the other poster's answer because he gave basically the same answer first, but that's very elegant indeed! I feel stupid now.

Comment: Not quite same: you can do arbitrary probabilities with this approach (e.g. `rand < 0.12834`).

Comment: Should it be `rand < 0.17` for the second case?

Comment: @sagarpandya82: I am not dealing with heads or tails, just with probabilities. If you want specific code, I guess it would be `rand < 0.67 ? :heads : :tails` and `rand < 0.83 ? :tails : :heads`... which could, obviously, be written in other ways, too.